# grant insert to role - no table specified

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I've come across this mystery in some SQL Server code I've inherited:

```
GRANT INSERT TO SomeUserRole
```

I would expect there to have to be a table or view to be specified. Running this works fine but doesn't appear to do anything. The role doesn't have rights to insert into any tables. Any ideas? I'd like to get rid of this if possible but if it is somehow giving the role some access, I'll have to keep it.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: The grammar at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) shows that the only required clauses are `GRANT <permission> TO <database_principal>` when this is given at the database level. There is no syntax at that level that restricts it to a specific table.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite - I hadn't fully tested this. It does indeed turn out that the role has insert permissions to every single table. A bit of a security hole! The code actually had the same for UPDATE and DELETE so I'm just going to add the role to db_datawriter. When I have time I'll try remove it from the role and see what breaks. It might be that those perms were granted unnecessarily as it looks like sprocs do everything.

Comment: If that answers your question completely, I'll go ahead and post it as an answer for future readers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grammar at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) shows that the only required clauses are GRANT  TO  when used at the database level. There is no syntax at that level that restricts it to a specific table.

```
GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ]  
    TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
    [ AS <database_principal> ]

<permission>::=  
permission | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ]

<database_principal> ::= 
        Database_user 
    | Database_role 
    | Application_role 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_User 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_Group 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_certificate 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_asymmetric_key 
    | Database_user_with_no_login
```